# Linking Google Maps API for business from OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api

I just came across a [web-page](https://drupal.org/node/2151043) about supplying private key from OpenLayers to Google Maps for business API. But checking on the Google Maps API page, it is asking for **signatures** which is hash of the query with a secret key for each request. I think it is for maps image requests also, which is contradicting with what the web-page says.

Can the Google Maps for business API be used with OpenLayers and, if so, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For license issues OpenLayers does not offers a google maps layers.

Here is a sample http://bl.ocks.org/elemoine/e82c7dd4b1d0ef45a9a4 on using OL3 with GMaps.

You can find a similar question at: [Overlaying Raster image with Google Maps in OpenLayers3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118294/overlaying-raster-image-with-google-maps-in-openlayers3)